# Django Form upload to AWS S3 with Boto3 results in empty file

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-views, django-forms

I am having a multipart/form-data form that should upload to a S3 bucket, using Boto3.

All is happening as expected, but at the end, the file at the S3 bucket has 0 bytes.

forms.py:

```
class DropOffFilesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(error_messages={'invalid_type': _("Please upload only PDF, JPG, PNG, XLS(x), DOC(x) files")},
                       validators=[
                           FileTypeValidator(allowed_types=['application/pdf', 'image/*', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'], allowed_extensions=['.pdf', '.png', '.jpg', '.doc', '.docx', '.xls', '.xlsx'])], required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label=_("Description"), required=False)

    def clean_description(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['description']
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = DropOffFiles
        exclude = ['filename',]
        fields = ['file', 'description']
```

views.py:

```
file_form = DropOffFilesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

if file_form.is_valid():

   file_form = file_form.save(commit=False)

   s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=settings.AWS_ZONE,
                           aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_KEY,
                           aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET)

   file = request.FILES['file']

   if file:

        file_type = file.content_type
        extension = file.name.split(".")[-1]

        # construct file name and location
        filename = calculate_md5(file) + '.'+extension

        # save the file
        try:
             response = s3.upload_fileobj(file, 'bucketname', filename)
        except ClientError as e:
             logging.error(e)
             return False



        file_form.filename = filename
        file_form.dropoff = dropoff
        file_form.save()
```

Happy for any suggestion.

Comment: `file` does not seem like a valid file object. Could please try with `response = s3.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(file.read()), 'bucketname', filename)`? Django also has [s3 storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) which could simplify handling files for you?

Comment: file is definitely filled. When I do print(file.read()) I get the content of my file. Also sys.getsizeof(file) shows the correct size for the object. Your io.BytesIO approach is something I also tested, but also results in an empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calculate_md5 does a read() on the InMemoryFile, which sets the cursor to the end of the file.

The right way is to reset the cursor using

```
file.file.seek(0)
```

and then recall it. This will set the cursor to the beginning and the content of the file is available.